# ParseFacebookUtilsV4 enable bitcode error xcode 7 beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode

First of all, I am aware of questions similar to this one but none of them refers to my problem. I am using Xcode 7 beta 6 and cocoapods.
This is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Alfred' do
pod 'PaymentKit', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/PaymentKit.git'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

When compiling for the simulator, all works fine, but when compiling for a real device (iPhone 6 with iOS 9 beta) I got the following error code:

> '/Users/username/projectpath/Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/libParseFacebookUtilsV4Lib.a(PFFacebookUtils.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target for architecture arm64

I have alredy enabled the flag ENABLE_BITCODE and it still shows the same error. Also I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project again.

Comment: Deleted my 'duplicate' flag. Just saw under the poor format that they have tried enabling bitcode with no results. Disregard flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to DISABLE bitcode for those libraries that do not support bitcode yet.

The error is saying please link your static lib that has been compiled for bitcode. Since you probably don't own the cocoapods libs you need to just disable bitcode support for those libraries in your project.

If you want the quick and dirty, just disable bitcode for your target (seen below). But you can more granularly pick and choose to disable bitcode for the libraries giving you trouble as well (more responsible choice).

[image]